# Finite groups with elements of order a prime power

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

> Consider a finite group $G$ where the order of each element is a power of a certain prime number $p$, then $G$ is a $p$-group.

My question: are there groups that are **not** $p$-groups, but for which the order of each element  is a power of a prime number?

Comment: Do you mean for a given fixed prime?

Comment: Not the same $p$, since the theorem in the quotation box would imply that $G$ is a $p$-group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G=\mathfrak{S}_3$ be the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$. The order of the elements is either $2$ or $3$. (Or $1$ for the trivial permutation).